# NUnit build step in TeamCity takes 4 times longer with dotCover analysis enabled

Tags: nunit, teamcity, dotcover

I have a build configuration on my TeamCity server that compiles the solution in one step and then runs about 1650 tests using an NUnit build step.

When the NUnit build step runs without coverage analysis it runs all the tests in about 25 minutes.
When I enable the dotCover analysis the run time shoots up to 100 minutes or higher.

This is making it rather impractical to run since the whole build ends up taking well over 2 hours,  but I'd still like to be able to get the coverage information so I'm reluctant to turn it off altogether.

Is there another configuration I could use that would allow me to run the tests can gather the coverage information faster?
Is there perhaps other configuration I could do on TeamCity in general or the build agent machine to speed this up?
Or is there be something I could do to the tests themselves that might speed things up?

Setup:

- TeamCity 9.1.1 with dotCover 3.1.1
- NUnit build running 2.6.1
- Referenced NUnit assembly 2.5.10

Comment: it's expected that a build with coverage analysis runs slower - do you truly need test coverage on every single run? In my projects, if I set up coverage then only once nightly, so it doesn't affect "normal" CI runs

Comment: Yes, that it would be a bit slower I would expect, it was just the magnitude of the difference that surprised me. On further investigation, the bulk of the time is accounted for by about 15 or so tests. I'm going to try to exclude those from the coverage test run and run them separately and see what difference that makes.

Comment: @Nanhydrin exactly same multiplier ='(